# styling google maps data layer

Tags: google-maps, postgis, geojson

I use data from Postgis, that is loaded via geojson and added as data layer on Google Maps.

```js
//Load mapdata via geoJson
var parzelle = new google.maps.Data();
parzelle.loadGeoJson("./mapdata/get_ugs_geojson.php");

// Set the stroke width, and fill color for each polygon
var featureStyle = {
  fillColor: '#ADFF2F',
  fillOpacity: 0.1,
  strokeColor: '#ADFF2F',
  strokeWeight: 1
}

// Apply style settings to data layer
parzelle.setStyle(featureStyle);

// Add data layer to map
parzelle.setMap(map);
```

I would like to style the displayed polygons depending on their attributes (in this case a habitat-code).
I've tried the following, but the polygons are no longer displayed.

```js
//Load mapdata via geoJson
var parzelle = new google.maps.Data();
parzelle.loadGeoJson("./mapdata/get_ugs_geojson.php");

// Styles depending on habitat
var styles = {
  6510: {fillColor: "#00cc00", fillOpacity: 0.1, strokeWeight: 1.5, strokeColor: "#00cc00", strokeOpacity: 0.8},
  6430: {fillColor: "#00cc00", fillOpacity: 0.1, strokeWeight: 1.5, strokeColor: "#00cc00", strokeOpacity: 0.8},
  6210: {fillColor: "#ff9900", fillOpacity: 0.1, strokeWeight: 1.5, strokeColor: "#ff9900", strokeOpacity: 0.8},
  9150: {fillColor: "#993300", fillOpacity: 0.1, strokeWeight: 1.5, strokeColor: "#993300", strokeOpacity: 0.8},
  9180: {fillColor: "#992200", fillOpacity: 0.1, strokeWeight: 1.5, strokeColor: "#992200", strokeOpacity: 0.8}
};

var habitat = parzelle.feature.getProperty ('fk_habitat_target');
var featureStyle = styles[habitat] || {};

parzelle.setStyle(featureStyle);
parzelle.setMap(map);
```

What's wrong with my code? or Maybe there is even a simpler way to style the polygons depending on their attributes?

Comment: What does your GeoJSON look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The way that dynamic styling of data layer features works is the following, and it's actually pretty cool: Instead of providing an object containing the styling to the `setStyle()` method, you provide a function that returns such an object. Inside that function, you can then react to the properties or anything else you like, in order to change the styling.

```js
var featureStyling = function(feature) {
  var StyleOptions = {
      fillColor: feature.getProperty('fk_habitat_target') == 6510
                  ? '#00cc00'
                  : '#993300'
  };
  return StyleOptions;
};
map.data.setStyle(featureStyling);
```

Of course, this is just a simplified example, you would probably use a switch/case statement to switch through the property and return a completely different StyleOptions object for each property value.